# Would this be a good candidate for reactive extensions?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a process for which I need to improve performance.

This process runs a query in the database.

For each record, there are 2 tasks that might have to be done, based on data in the record.

For one of the two tasks, additional info might need to be fetched from a web service, then, processing is exactly the same.

The other task is always the same.

Once both task are done, the record must be updated in the database.

I think Rx could allow me to run processes in parallel which would improve performance. Also, I would like to be able to monitor the progress of the batch.

Currently, I have the following code. I would like to know if this seems a valid approach for this task.

```
IObservable<Record> records = GetDataFromDb().ToObservable();

var recsOfType1 = records.Where(r => r.IsOfType1).Do(FetchAdditionalInfoIntoRecord);
var recsOfType2 = records.Where(r => r.IsOfType2);

var allCompleteRecords = recsOfType1.Merge(recsOfType2);

allCompleteRecords.Do(Task1).Do(Task2).Do(UpdateInDB);
```

I would need to add additional error handling and monitoring of the process. I am not 100% sure how I would approach that.

Any ideas/comments/critics welcome.

Thanks

Comment: No. RX is meant for 'managing' streams of events. So to process data that is pushed. DB querying is about pulling data. Instead I suggest looking at tasks.

Comment: Rx is overkill. Task should help here

Comment: I agree with all comments that this is not an Rx problem. But would also like to add "dont use `Do` like that". If you did have an observable sequence of data, then use `Select` to make changes to the data and _pipe_ it to the next operator. Dont use to `Do` which should almost exclusively be relegated to logging and debugging.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments mentioned, Rx is best for push-based streams. All these tasks are pull-based. If you feel that the standard Tasks don't cut it, then I would recommend [TPL-Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Database queries, files, registries, etc. are pull-based (Enumerable) as opposed to push-based (Observable). Instead of Reactive Extensions, you could use the Interactive Extensions (`System.Interactive`) - they contain most of the equivalent methods in Rx, but are pull-based.

Enumerable generators allow you to write co-routines (via `yield`), and are a powerful compositional tool. If you want asynchrony, you simply can wrap the enumeration in Tasks.